# Web Page with dynamic dashboard using liquid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, liquid

I'm creating a dynamic web page which needs to display (possibly) many col-md-4 for each row (I mean HTML tags), all this using a for on a string array.

Here is the code:

```
<h1><i class="fa fa-pie-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Global Dashboard</h1>
<div class="container" id="global-dashboard">

  {%- assign ListResult = "6,99,4,6,8" -%}
  {%- assign ListResult = ListResult | split: "," -%}
  
  {%- for result in ListResult -%}
    {%- assign resultModule = forloop.index0 | modulo: columnNumber -%}
    {%- if forloop.index0 == 0 -%}
      <div class="row">
      {%- elsif resultModule == 0 -%}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
    {%- endif -%}
      <div class="col-md-4 col-dashboard-enx">
      <p class="data-aggregation-number">{{ result }}</p>
      <p class="data-aggregation-description">{{ "any string about description" }}</p>
      </div>
    {%- if forloop.last == true -%}
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
</div>
```

It creates all the col-md-4 on the same row, but I don't know why.

P.S. I noticed the module doesn't fill the variable

Comment: What's the html resulting looks like?

Comment: i finally resolved it using the "module" function, since i wanted to display 3 col for each row. It work well now :)